# Historical Hurricane data

Tags: data, table, natural-disaster

I am searching for a data source on past hurricanes that includes the coordinates of the path at different times including wind speed pressure and category. Any other added data would also be helpful.

Comment: May be worth asking this at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cross-posted as https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/13260/6229

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://weather.unisys.com/hurricanes

It has got data from 1851 to 2017 it has:

- time
- lat-long
- wind
- pressure

or https://www.data.gov/disasters/hurricanes/

it has storm surges, heavy rainfall, high winds, tornadoes, rip currents, and flooding.

or https://www.wunderground.com/hurricane/hurrarchive.asp

or https://www.climate.gov/maps-data/dataset/historical-hurricane-tracks-gis-map-viewer

https://toolkit.climate.gov/tool/historical-hurricane-tracks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [NOAA GIS data portal](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/).  There are lots of resources and links on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find such data at the "International Best Track Archive for Climate Stewardship (IBTrACS)" https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/ibtracs/index.php?name=ibtracs-data

This includes much more than just hurricanes.